# Set additional ansible module parameter only if variable is defined

Tags: ansible

I have a custom ansible module.

```
 10 def main():                                                                                                                                          
 11     module = AnsibleModule(                                                                                                                          
 12             argument_spec = dict(                                                                                                                    
 13                 server = dict(required=True, type='str'),                                                                                            
 14                 max_offset = dict(required=False, default=0.100, type='float')                                                                       
 15             ),                                                                                                                                       
 16             supports_check_mode = False                                                                                                              
 17         )                                                                                                                                            
 18                                                                                                                                                      
 19     # Write params into normal variables                                                                                                             
 20     max_offset = module.params['max_offset']                                                                                                         
 21     server = module.params.get('server')
```

I want to call it with additional parameter only if a variable `ntp.max_offset` is defined.
I dont know how to do this.
So I tried this code:

```
- name: GROUP::TEST                                                                                                                                 
  ntptest: server="{{ hostvars[item][eth]['ipv4']['address'] }}"                                                                                    
  parameter:                                                                                                                                        
    name: "max_offset"                                                                                                                              
    value: ntp.max_offset                                                                                                                           
    when: ntp.max_offset is defined                                                                                                                 
  register: modules_output                                                                                                                          
  with_items: "{{groups['ntp_servers']}}"                                                                                                           
  when: server is not defined
```

But unfortunately.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `default(omit)` (see ["Making variables optional"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional)) eg:

```
- name: GROUP::TEST
  ntptest: 
    server: "{{ hostvars[item][eth]['ipv4']['address'] }}"
    max_offset: "{{ ntp.max_offset | default(omit) }}"
```

This causes the value not to be sent to the module when the variable is undefined.

Comment: Is this still expected to work if you have to quote your variable, like `"{{ ntp.max_offset | default(omit) | quote }}"`. The quote has to come after the default, otherwise I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was a bit different

The variable I refer to (`net_ssl_mode`) is always set and I need to value the argument with something else than `true` or `false`

#### Solution

Use `ternary()` and `omit`

```yaml
argument: "{{ ( condition ) | ternary("value_if_cond_true", omit) }}"
```

cf. [making-variables-optional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) and [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-different-values-for-true-false-null-ternary)

#### "full" example

```yaml
vars:
  # always set:
  net_tls_ca_file: "/path/ca.crt"

  # Always set to one of ["TLS", "disabled"]
  net_ssl_mode: "TLS"


tasks:
  - name: "Use module"
    module_with_some_optional_arguments:
      (...)
      tlsCAFile: "{{ (net_ssl_mode != 'disabled') | ternary(net_tls_ca_file, omit) }}"
      tls: "{{ (net_ssl_mode != 'disabled') | ternary(true, omit) }}"
```

hth