# Ansible Custom Module: How to implement conditional parameter?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

I want to create a Custom Module call API which will take

- `action`: `get` or `search`
- `resource`: `car`/`truck`/`plane`/`ship`
- optional parameters - dynamic parameter based on `action` and `resource`

For example if `action` is `get` and `resource` is `car`, then I want to add `wheels`, `doors` as module parameter.

```py
module_args = {
        'action': {'required': True, 'type': 'str', choice:['get','search']},
        'resource': {'required': True, 'type': 'str', choice: ['car', 'truck', 'ship']},
         }

module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=module_args,
         required_if('resource', 'car', ('wheels', 'doors'))
         supports_check_mode=True
         )
```

Is there a way to put `required_if` on two options i.e `if action == 'search' and resource =='car'` then use different set of arguments?

Comment: I don't think there's specific support for that, but you can perform whatever addittional validations you want after instantiating your `AnsibleModule`.

Comment: But you could set `module_args` of `wheels` or `doors` to `optional` upfront and check later on the requirements within the module. Or maybe do the validation with the Ansible playbook or task as in [Set additional Ansible module parameter only if variable is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885689/).

Comment: I am just wondering if documentation example about [argument_spec `required_if`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#argument-spec) isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for a way to avoid writing multiple if else conditions as I have a large set of option, apparently that's the only option.